# Connection between Symmetry Breaking and RG flow

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, renormalization, phase-transition

I was wondering if this interpretation of how RG flows connects to the conventional symmetry breaking description of phase transitions is correct.

Say I am an experimentalist and I move through parameter space by tuning some knob in my experiment (say temperature). As I move, I go through different RG basins of attraction: these different basins of attraction have our long distance theory flow to different fixed points, and the symmetries of different theories will be different.

Is this correct? This interpretation seems to sidestep the fundamental role symmetry plays in phase transitions that I seem to gather from different sources on phase transitions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you think is being "sidestepped"?

Comment: I mean that when we talk about say Landau-Ginzburg for a $\phi^4$ theory, there is great emphasis on the fact that breaking the $Z_2$ symmetry is the sign of a phase transition. But in the description I give above, symmetry is more of an after thought and the primary signature of a phase transition is you just have a different long distance theory.